# Splitting train & validation set for seq2seq model

Tags: python, dataset

I don't understand how and how much this function is splitting the dataset into training dataset and validation dataset. I wanted to split it myself but I don't understand how. Can someone explain how it is splitting my dataset?

```
train_source = source_int_text[batch_size:]
train_target = target_int_text[batch_size:]
valid_source = source_int_text[:batch_size]
valid_target = target_int_text[:batch_size]

def pad_word_batch(word_batch, pad_int):

    max_word = max([len(word) for word in word_batch])
    return [word + [pad_int] * (max_word - len(word)) for word in word_batch]


def get_batches(sources, targets, batch_size, source_pad_int, target_pad_int):

    for batch_i in range(0, len(sources)//batch_size):
        start_i = batch_i * batch_size

        # Slice the right amount for the batch
        sources_batch = sources[start_i:start_i + batch_size]
        targets_batch = targets[start_i:start_i + batch_size]

        # Pad
        pad_sources_batch = np.array(pad_word_batch(sources_batch, source_pad_int))
        pad_targets_batch = np.array(pad_word_batch(targets_batch, target_pad_int))


        # Need the lengths for the _lengths parameters
        pad_targets_lengths = []
        for target in pad_targets_batch:
            pad_targets_lengths.append(len(target))

        pad_source_lengths = []
        for source in pad_sources_batch:
            pad_source_lengths.append(len(source))

        yield pad_sources_batch, pad_targets_batch, pad_source_lengths, pad_targets_lengths

(valid_sources_batch, valid_targets_batch, valid_sources_lengths, valid_targets_lengths ) = next(Batch_Metrics.get_batches(valid_source,
                                                                                                             valid_target,
                                                                                                             batch_size,
                                                                                                             source_vocab_to_int['<PAD>'],
                                                                                                             target_vocab_to_int['<PAD>']))                                                                                                  

#Starting the the session
with tf.Session(graph=train_graph) as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

    for epoch_i in range(epochs):
        for batch_i, (source_batch, target_batch, sources_lengths, targets_lengths) in enumerate(
                Batch_Metrics.get_batches(train_source, train_target, batch_size,
                            source_vocab_to_int['<PAD>'],
                            target_vocab_to_int['<PAD>'])):

            _, loss = sess.run(
                [train_op, cost],
                {input_data: source_batch,
                 targets: target_batch,
                 lr: learning_rate,
                 target_sequence_length: targets_lengths,
                 keep_prob: keep_probability})


            if batch_i % display_step == 0 and batch_i > 0:
                batch_train_logits = sess.run(
                    inference_logits,
                    {input_data: source_batch,
                     target_sequence_length: targets_lengths,
                     keep_prob: 1.0})

                batch_valid_logits = sess.run(
                    inference_logits,
                    {input_data: valid_sources_batch,
                     target_sequence_length: valid_targets_lengths,
                     keep_prob: 1.0})

                train_acc = Batch_Metrics.get_accuracy(target_batch, batch_train_logits)
                valid_acc = Batch_Metrics.get_accuracy(valid_targets_batch, batch_valid_logits)
                print('Epoch {:>3} Batch {:>3}/{} - Train Accuracy: {:>6.4f}, Validation Accuracy: {:>6.4f}, Loss: {:>6.4f}'
                      .format(epoch_i+1, batch_i, len(source_int_text) // batch_size, train_acc, valid_acc, loss))
```

I can't understand how and where its splitting the dataset. All I can understand is its splitting data with respect to batches. Can someone explain how its splitting data and in which format, like 90:10 or something else? And what do I need to do if I want it to split into 90:10 or 80:20 or any other ratio? And how to shuffle data for every epoch(only training)? I know there is a function Tensorflow.data.shuffle() but how can I apply it in my code? Should I make an object an call it after calculating `train_acc` and `valid_acc`?

Comment: Variable display_step is not defined, where are you defining it ?

Comment: im initialising all the parameters at start, sorry for not including them in my post. display_step is to displays no. of steps. im using display_step = 200